# Is congruence and equality the same thing?

Tags: number-theory

I am studying for a number theory class and I was wondering if congruence is similar to "=" in that that order of left hand side versus right hand side of an equals sign does not matter?

Comment: If $a\equiv b\bmod m$ then $b\equiv a\bmod m$.  That's because $a\equiv b\bmod m$ means $m|(a-b)$ i.e. $mx=a-b$ with $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, and if the latter is true then $m(-x) = b-a$. Not sure if this is what you're asking.

Comment: HINT: What are the required conditions for a relation to be an equivalence relation? Is equality an equivalence relation? What about congruence? If you can answer these questions you should know what you need to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, perfectly correct. For suppose that $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$. Then by definition $m$ divides $a-b$. It follows that $m$ divides $b-a$, so $b\equiv a\pmod{m}$.

Congruence is like equality in other ways. For example, $a\equiv a\pmod{m}$. Also, if $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $b\equiv c\pmod{m}$, then $a\equiv c\pmod{m}$. So congruence is an *equivalence relation*.

Congruence behaves like equality in other important ways. Suppose that $a\equiv c\pmod{m}$ and $b\equiv d\pmod{m}$. Then $a+b\equiv c+d\pmod{m}$ and $ab\equiv cd\pmod{m}$.

But although congruence and equality have structural properties in common, they are certainly not *the same*. And some important properties of equality can fail. For example, $4\cdot 2\equiv 4\cdot 6\pmod{8}$, but $2\not\equiv 6\pmod{8}$.